Trouble with Spring Boot Security and Custom Login Page Authentication
Details of the problem:
I'm encountering a CORS error while attempting to authenticate with Spring Boot Security on a custom login page in my application. Specifically, when I submit the login form, I receive the following error message:
rust
Copy code
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/login;jsessionid=3E156EB3B56F772B61F5D5CF363B011E' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/perform_login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
Additionally, in the console, I see:
vbnet
Copy code
TypeError: Failed to fetch
To provide context, I'm relatively new to Spring Boot, React, and TypeScript. I'm working on implementing authentication for a simple login page in my application. Here's a breakdown of the issue:
Spring Boot Security Configuration: I've configured Spring Boot Security to permit access to certain URLs, handle form-based authentication, and set up CORS to allow requests from my React frontend.
React Login Page: My login page is a React component that sends a POST request to the Spring Boot backend upon form submission. It captures the username and password, constructs a JSON payload, and sends it to the backend URL "/perform_login".
Despite configuring CORS to allow requests from the origin "http://localhost:3000" and handling form submission properly in my React component, I'm still encountering this CORS error. I suspect there might be an issue with how Spring Boot Security handles authentication and redirects, but I'm unsure how to resolve it.
I've included both my Spring Boot Security configuration and the code for my React login page for reference. Any insights or guidance on what might be causing this error and how I can fix it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
here is my security config file
package com.example.backend.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/login", "/resources/**", "/static/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login") // You can customize login page URL here
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login") // URL where login form POSTs to
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        var user = User.withUsername("user")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}


In attempting to resolve the CORS error with Spring Boot Security and my custom login page, I ensured that my Spring Boot Security configuration allowed CORS requests from the frontend origin. Additionally, I verified that my React login page correctly sent a POST request with the user credentials to the backend endpoint.
I expected that the authentication process would succeed without encountering CORS issues, allowing users to log in successfully. However, despite these efforts, I continued to receive the CORS error upon form submission.
Instead of successful authentication, the error message persisted, preventing users from logging in and resulting in a "TypeError: Failed to fetch" in the console.

The answer is likely that the login endpoint is replying with a redirect upon successful authentication (or as a matter of fact, unsuccessful authentication).
The typical solution is to use HTTP Basic or JWT-based authentication instead (httpBasic or oauth2ResourceServer instead of formLogin). These are suited better for a Javascript frontend authenticating to a backend.
If you must use formLogin, configure it with handlers that don't redirect but respond with status codes like so:
.loginPage("/login")
.loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login") 
.successHandler((request, response, auth) -> response.setStatus(200))
.failureHandler((request, response, ex) -> response.setStatus(401))


That worked! Now I am getting a 404 error, not its from the skillet to the frying pan! CORS is now set buy now there is something is wrong.
